# Get the latest file from SFTP server using Node.js

Tags: node.js, ssh, sftp

I need help with finding a working solution for how to download the **latest** (added most recently) file from a remote SFTP server (which can be running on both UNIX and Windows machines), using a Node.js script.

Solutions I have already attempted:

1. Using the standard `list` method (provided in any sftp library in Node.js), retrieve a list of all files on the server, sort them by timestamp, find the latest file's name, and then use the `get` SFTP method.
   Problem with this solution is that the server has **up to 20k files**, and retrieving all their names through the standard `list` method is extremely slow, I need a faster solution.
2. Through `SSH2` library, connect to the remote server, execute a sample command (I used `echo "$PATH"` ⁠— response from a Windows machine would be `"$PATH"`, while UNIX machines return their $PATH variable) and determine the server's OS. After determining the OS, I would execute another command, through SSH again, to sort through the files in particular path/location and return the name of the most recent one (e.g. for UNIX, the command would be `ls -t | awk \'{printf("%s",$0);exit}\'`). Having gotten the file name, I would just use the `get` SFTP method to download the file with name found.
   Problem: this solution is  extremely error-prone, and testing it on 100s of servers is one hell of a job.

I need recommendations for any other solution, library, anything.

Comment: Be aware that file *creation* time may not be available on all filesystems/OSes.